# Replace all occurrences of x in PR

Tags: git

So I've got a PR on GitHub which I have made, and it's been reviewed to change a field from `status` to `result`. I want to search for all occurrences of `status` *within the PR*, since `status` is used all over the code base. I hatched the following master plan:

1. `git diff my-branch origin/master > patch.txt`
2. change all the occurrences there
3. create a new branch `my-branch-2` off master
4. `git apply patch.txt` on the new branch `my-branch-2`
5. `git commit; git push`
6. `git merge my-branch-2` into `my-branch`

Unfortunately it failed at step 4 with non-existent files `error: patch/to/file.py: No such file or directory` or, just didn't work `error: path/to/file2.py: patch does not apply`

What's the smartest way about doing this rename?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather simply use the branch pushed as a PR, checkout it, change the text, make a new commit and push.

If that branch is not available, I would [checkout that pull request locally](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), then do the aforementioned steps: a simple search and replace, commit and push, to update the GitHub PR.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a really old question but might be still relevant to others.

**Tip**: Ensure you create a backup in case things go wrong

The following steps worked for me (I just had one commit)

1. `git show commit_id > patch.txt`
2. Using any standard editor or `sed` to make all the changes
3. `git reset --hard HEAD~1` This deletes the commit!
4. `git apply patch.txt`
5. Add and commit the changes

#### Alternate for steps 3 to step 5

Instead of deleting the commit in step 3, one could preserve the original patch(`patch.txt`) and create a `modified_patch.txt` for all the changes, and
then do the following:

1. `git apply --reverse patch.txt`
2. `git apply modified_patch.txt`

On a side note, I think the issue with your steps could be because of:

1. `master` and `origin/master` being at different commits causing the patch to fail.
2. `git apply -v patch.txt` might provide more info